# Moderation. Should I delete my question?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, comments

I asked this question [handling login/logout redirects](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38810/handling-login-logout-redirects) It was helpful and what I wanted and it will probably help someone else.

However the comments have devolved and gone off-topic and not really what I would want anyone else to see.

The fact that some feel they don't agree with my opinions about not wanting to use a lot of plugins for a few minor features (Which I didn't even ask about or imply for that matter, not until someone asked.) doesn't mean I don't have the right to ask for a different solution just like I can't tell someone what they should or shouldn't answer. Right?

Someone was so incensed at my preference for a coded solution he even edited out the reference to it in my question!

It's partly my fault, I shouldn't have continued the conversation. I have a hard letting go :)

Should I leave or delete my question or can the comments be moderated by someone else somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I have cleaned it up.

You kinda asked for it (lesson learned I hope), but the response you got for it did not contribute to improving your question.

Your last edit seems perfectly reasonably formulated to me and better explanation why you want it that way, than original form of it.

Comment: Thank you very much!